# NMinimize with list as variable starting point

Tags: mathematical-optimization

`FindMinimum` has a very convenient feature:

> If the starting point for a variable is given as a list, the values of
>   the variable are taken to be lists with the same dimensions.

I do not find a similar feature for `NMinimize`. Is there a simple work around?

Answer (score 2):

Just reading the documentation for [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) tells you that this feature is not present. Furthermore, `NMinimize` does not take *"starting point for a variable"*, so that is necessarily so.

Now if what you want is to find the $\vec{x}$ that minimizes $f(\vec{x})$, for example for dimension 5, and using Norm as ans example function

```
f = Norm;
With[{xx = Array[x, 5]},
 NMinimize[f[xx], xx]
 ]
```

Or you could define something like this

```
NVectorMinimize[f_, x_, n_] := Block[
  {
   xx = Array[Unique[], n],
   fmin,
   vec,
   func = Function[x, f][xx]
   },
  {fmin, vec} = NMinimize[func, xx];
  {fmin, x -> (xx /. vec)}
  ]


NVectorMinimize[f[x], x, 4]
(* {1.9299*10^-11, x -> {-2.5935*10^-12, -1.0298*10^-11, -9.0777*10^-13, -1.6089*10^-11}} *)
```